# Inject Dependency during model binding microsoft web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

In my MVC projects, I have a custom default model binder which uses the dependency resolver to inject services into the model when it is created by the model binder. Thus I can have a membership service or a queryable session inside the model to do validation, keeping it out of the controller.

```
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.IsGenericType)
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);

        return _dependencyResolver.GetService(modelType);
    }`
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in Microsoft Web API? The IModelBinder doesn't provide a CreateModel method to override, and having searched, I can't see any way to do this.

Comment: So you want to inject a service into your ModelBinder instance correct (maybe I am not reading it right)? Have you tried using injection into the constructor of your ModelBinder? It might also depend on which injection framework you are using, some are more limited than others.

Comment: When the model binder creates a model, I want to inject any required services. Say I have UpdateUserModel(ISession session). I want the model binder to inject this so I can query the session in UpdateUserModel.Validate().

Using ninject as the framework

Comment: I just did some searching and I can't find a way to do it at the time the model is created either.

Answer (score 0):

Bonno, WebAPI automatically resolves, or tries to resolve the model in the controller as long as the you use a specific model type. Check [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value
>   from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>   bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>   and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>   a string. (More about type converters later.) For complex types, Web
>   API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type
>   formatter.

For example:

```
[Route("api/myApi")]
 public HttpStatusCode Post(SomeModelType modelObject)
{ ... }
```

if the posted json object can be resolved to SomeModelType , then an instance of the SomeModelType is created in the form of modelObject.

The whole point being that you don't need your own dependency resolver. However, if you still want to have one for whatever reason, the JToken parameter type will any and all objects. It would be your responsibility to deserialize and handle the object in a similar fashion as in MVC.

**EDIT**

---

After reading your comments I realized that you were talking about dependency injection. Because of the way WebAPI works in resolving parameters I would not recommend injecting dependencies into your controller functions, but rather have your controller instantiate a class in which the dependencies are injected via the constructor or otherwise, and leave it to your dependency container/injector to do that job.